# Let $\left\{\Delta_1,\Delta_2,.....,\Delta_n\right\}$ be the set of all determinants of order 3 that can be made with the distinct real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $\left\{\Delta_1,\Delta_2,.....,\Delta_n\right\}$ be the set of all determinants of order 3 that can be made with the distinct real numbers from the set $S=\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,8,9\right\}$.Then prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Delta_i=0$

---

I know that the total number of determinants that can be formed by using distinct real numbers from the given set is $9!$.But i dont know how to prove that their sum is zero.Please help me.Thanks

Comment: Does the answer i have posted solve your doubts ?

Comment: I could not understand how will we show it mathematically.This is a subjective question.I need to show the work and calculations.

Comment: @navinstudent Can you explain in more detail what it is you think the current answers are missing?  In what sense it is a subjective question, and why do you think such a question requires calculation?

Answer (score 10):

Note that if you swap two columns of a matrix, its determinant is multiplied by $-1$.  So let's say that two matrices $A$ and $B$ made up of the numbers in $S$ are equivalent if either $A=B$ or $A$ is obtained from $B$ by swapping the first two columns.  This is an equivalence relation, and each equivalence class has two elements.  The sum of the determinants within each equivalence class is $0$.  Thus by partitioning the entire sum into these equivalence classes, we find that the total sum is $0$.

Comment: We might want to add a few words on matrices whose first two columns are identical.

Comment: Matrices where the first two columns are identical automatically have determinant 0, so they don't change the sum. I'm not sure why this answer isn't detailed enough, it seems to explain why the sum is 0 pretty clearly.

Comment: @D.Thomine There are no matrices whose first two columns are identical, since the entries are a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,9\}$.  But it's nice that the argument generalizes further due to the vanishing determinant (my almost-identical answer does not depend on drawing any such distinction).

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood "made from the set" as "entries are between 1 and 9". Now the enumeration of those matrices make more sense. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 8):

A symmetry argument suffices.  Note that swapping, say, the first two rows of each of the $n$ matrices causes the determinants to change sign.  If we sum those up we will surely get $-\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta_i$.  On the other hand, this row swap operation is an involution on the set of matrices formed from $S$: so we just get the same set of $n!$ determinants, but in a different order.  Thus

$$-\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta_i,$$

so both sides are $0$.

Answer (score 6):

We have $det(A) = a_{11}a_{22}a_{33} + a_{12}a_{23}a_{31} + a_{13}a_{21}a_{32} -a_{11}a_{23}a_{32} - a_{13}a_{22}a_{31} - a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}$. There are $9!$ such sums. So each term in this sum will be the same (eg. $\Sigma a_{11}a_{22}a_{33} = \Sigma a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}$) , and there are exactly equal number of positive and negative terms, so the result is zero.

Comment: I truly, honestly, had no idea you were referring to this approach in your previous answer.  This new answer is much clearer, thank you!  But I believe you mean there are $3!$ sums, each having $9!$ terms.

Comment: @ErickWong. True. I had not written it clearly. Yes 6 sums, 9! times. Even this answer, I would like to write more elegantly